# When I build a Docker file, I get an error saying build failed

Tags: node.js, docker

I'm trying to build an image of my node application but when I run

```
docker build -t app .
```

I get this errors on linux:

> Dockerfile:11
>
> 11 | >>> RUN npm install
>
> ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c npm install" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1

Dockerfile:

```
# ...
FROM node:14

# ...
WORKDIR /app

# ...
COPY package*.json ./

# ...
RUN npm install

# ...
COPY . .

# ...
EXPOSE 3000

# ...
CMD ["node", "requests.js"]

#...
```

I cannot understand what I'm doing wrong ...

Comment: Try `COPY package.json ./`

Comment: @Philippe i have the same error ... i create a link on [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/Z6TwseHV) to see the message error

Comment: It looks like a network problem. I have  checked and run your Dockerfile with no problem

Comment: @MWY how its possible? I can ran other projects on linux. Why this error appears.